# XHR request undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm bit stuck, i have two functions that call a fill and return the result with JSON.parse. But when i console.log the result i get "undefined".

This is my function that handles the requests:

```
function caller(url,cfunc){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
                xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
}
function call_data(url,data){
    caller(url,function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            return( JSON.parse (xmlhttp.responseText) );
        }
    });                                           
}
```

The call is here:

```
result = call_data('./chk_login.php',0);
console.log(result);
```

According to Chrome im getting the xhr request perfectly fine and shows the output. But console.log shows undefined... so you know this is my PHP script too:

```
<?
    $var = 1;
    echo json_encode($var);
    exit;
?>
```

What could be causing the problem ???

Hope you can help!
Thanks!

Comment: Any reason not to use a Javascriot framework such as JQuery?

Comment: Because I don't want to use jQuery or any framework for that matter ?

Comment: `call_data` doesn't return anything...

Comment: Would it not with : `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;` ? That executes the function

Comment: Because he doesn't need to import a giant framework for a simple XHR?

Comment: @Dave I completely understand why you don't want to use a big framework for a simple ajax request, I was just checking if you were aware of other alternatives. I'm not selling any JS framework and it was not my intention to tell you what to do, sorry if it sounded that way.

Comment: It's okay, alot of people seem to throw "use jQuery" as a reply quite often these days. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is asynchronous (that's what the A in AJAX stands for, after all), you can't simply `return` a value and expect it to come back magically.  Instead, manipulate the data within a callback (you're 80% of the way there already).

```
function call_data(url,data){
    caller(url,function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            console.log( JSON.parse (xmlhttp.responseText) );
            ajaxResult = JSON.parse (xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    });
}

var ajaxResult;
```